# Retrieve hidden type of a phantom type

Tags: haskell, phantom-types

I declared a a phantom type like this with Haskell.

```
newtype Length (a::UnitLength) b = Length b deriving (Eq,Show)
data UnitLength = Meter
                | KiloMeter
                | Miles
                deriving (Eq,Show)
```

Now, I would like to write some functions to use this type. But I didn't happened to see and use the hidden type.

**Is it possible to retrieve the hidden type `a` of the phantom type `Length` to perform test, pattern matching, .... ?**

Comment: The simplest way to do any computation with types is with type classes. What function in particular would you want to write?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want a runtime representation of the phantom type you have used, you have to use what we call a singleton. It has precisely one constructor for each ones of the constructors in `UnitLength` and their types say precisely which constructor we are considering:

```
data SUnitLength (a :: UnitLength) where
  SMeter     :: SUnitLength Meter
  SKiloMeter :: SUnitLength KiloMeter
  SMiles     :: SUnitLength Miles
```

Now that you have this you can for instance write a display function picking the right unit abbreviation depending on the phantom parameter:

```
display :: Show b => SUnitLength a -> Length a b -> String
display sa l = show (payload l) ++
  case sa of
    SKiloMeter -> "km"
    _          -> "m"
```

Now, that does not really match your demand: the parameter `a` is available in the type `Length a b` but we somehow still have to manufacture the witness by hand. That's annoying. One way to avoid this issue is to define a type class doing that work for us. `CUnitLength a` tells us that provided a value of type `Length a b`, we can get a witness `SUnitLength a` of the shape `a` has.

```
class CUnitLength (a :: UnitLength) where
  getUnit :: Length a b -> SUnitLength a
```

It is easy for us to write instances of `CUnitLength` for the various `UnitLength` constructors: `getUnit` can even ignore its argument!

```
instance CUnitLength Meter where
  getUnit _ = SMeter

instance CUnitLength KiloMeter where
  getUnit _ = SKiloMeter

instance CUnitLength Miles where
  getUnit _ = SMiles
```

So why bother with `getUnit`'s argument? Well if we remove it, `getUnit` needs to somehow magically guess which `a` it is suppose to describe. Sometimes it's possible to infer that ̀`a` based on the expected type at the call site but sometimes it's not. Having the `Length a b` argument guarantees that all calls will be unambiguous. We can always recover a simpler `getUnit'` anyway:

```
getUnit' :: CUnitLength a => SUnitLength a
getUnit' = getUnit (undefined :: Length a ())
```

Which leads us to the last definition `display'` which has the same role as `display` but does not require the extra argument:

```
display' :: (CUnitLength a, Show b) => Length a b -> String
display' = display getUnit'
```

I have put everything (including the LANGUAGE extensions, and the definition of `payload` to extract a `b` from `Length a b`) in a [self-contained gist](https://gist.github.com/gallais/b08d7ba495ea2e91968c) in case you want to play with the code.

Comment: The fact that `SUnitLength` is a GADT, and therefore closed, seems a bit awkward. Further, I don't see why you'd want to pattern match on the unit. Would something like a data family be more appropriate?

Comment: `UnitLength` was already closed so it was impossible to use `Length` with anything but the three provided units.

Comment: Well yes, but couldn't that be swapped out for `*` or something?